# Жаннівна чи Жанівна

Tags: власні-назви, словотворення

Зустріла обидва варіанти написання [Жанівна](https://declarations.com.ua/declaration/nacp_f9a541ff-adb3-49b1-96e0-93f193791ab4) та [Жаннівна](https://declarations.com.ua/declaration/nacp_2101289e-f4b7-437c-b39b-39237401b78d). Чи потрібно подвоєння в по батькові Жанівна?

[ПРАВОПИС СУФІКСІВ](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par22p10)

> § 22. Іменникові суфікси 
>    -ОВИЧ, -ІВН(А) [-ЇВН(А)]
>
> При творенні жіночих імен по батькові вживається суфікс -івн(а), від
>   імен на -й — -ївн(а): Борисівна,
>   Василівна; Гордіївна, Сергіївна, Юріївна. /31/

Нічого не зазначено про подвоєння приголосних.

Answer (score 1):

Залежить від імені батька. За результатами пошуку Гугл, існує варіант Жанн, Йоханн, Йоанн... Якщо в його написанні наявне подвійне -нн, то і по-батькові буде Жаннівна, Йоханнівна, Йоаннівна.